# Error when migrating from Swift1.2 to Swift 2 : "value of type "UIViewController" has no member 'className'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I just migrated my Swift 1.2 code to Swift 2 code and I got the error

> value of type "`UIViewController`" has no member '`className`'

on this line:

`if(childViewController.className=="myPhotoCalendar.GalleryController")`

Here is my code :

```
func initLeftMenuController()
{
    for childViewController in self.childViewControllers
    {
        if(childViewController.className=="myPhotoCalendar.GalleryController")
        {
            self.galleryController=childViewController as! GalleryController
        }
        if(childViewController.className=="myPhotoCalendar.TextsController")
        {
            self.textsController=childViewController as! TextsController
        }
        if(childViewController.className=="myPhotoCalendar.TemplatesController")
        {
            self.templatesController=childViewController as! TemplatesController
        }
        if(childViewController.className=="myPhotoCalendar.StylesController")
        {
            self.stylesController=childViewController as! StylesController
        }
        if(childViewController.className=="myPhotoCalendar.ObjektsController")
        {
            self.objektsController=childViewController as! ObjektsController
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea of the equivalent of `className` in Swift 2 ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for class name similarity is not a good idea at all - use `if let` instead. What would you do if you change the name of a class? That might not be covered via refactoring and the app would stop working.

The best solution therefore is not looking for an alternative for `className` but use the better and more "swifty" way - something like

```
if let ctrl = childViewController as? GalleryController {
    self.galleryController = ctrl
} else if (...) {
    ...
}
```

Or use a switch statement (as Martin stated) (which I did not know was possible until looking it up):

```
switch childViewController {
case let ctrl as GalleryController:
    self.galleryController = ctrl
case let ctrl as SomeOtherClass:
    self.something = ctrl
// more cases
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: ... or a switch statement.

Comment: @MartinR did not know about that one - always nice to learn something new :)